# Authenticated and public routes in Backbone Marionette

Tags: javascript, authentication, backbone.js, marionette

We have a large Marionette app, with sub apps/modules.

Each of these registers its own router within the `App.addInitializer`.

What is the **best way to flag certain routes as public** and others as requiring authentication?

I have a way in the app to check if the user is authenticated or not, but I'm trying to avoid having to implement that check in every route handler.

```
PrivateModuleRouter.Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
  appRoutes: {
    "privateRoute(/)" : "handlePrivateRoute",
  }
});

var API = {
  handlePrivateRoute: function() {

   //I don't want to repeat this everywhere..

    if(!Auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      App.navigate('/login', {trigger:true});
    } else {
      PrivateRouteController.showForm();
    }
};

App.addInitializer(function(){
  new PrivateModuleRouter.Router({
    controller: API
  });
});
```

Is there way in the route definition to flag it as private, and then a top level route handler performs this check?

If it's on a `Router` event though, this may not trigger if the route handler was triggered directly (not passing `trigger:true`, and calling `API.handlePrivateRoute()` directly.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? If an answer helped you, you should accept it, or create your own answer if nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: as I don't personally use Marionette, this answer is based on Backbone only.*

## The execute function

Backbone provides the [`execute`](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-execute) function in the router as a way to handle that kind of logic. Even the example has authentication logic in it:

> ```
> var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
>   execute: function(callback, args, name) {
>     if (!loggedIn) {
>       goToLogin();
>       return false;
>     }
>     args.push(parseQueryString(args.pop()));
>     if (callback) callback.apply(this, args);
>   }
> });
> ```

## The authentication router

One way to avoid repeating the execute in each router would be to make a base router for your app.

```
var BaseRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    constructor: function(prefix, opt) {
        // get the hash
        this.auth = _.result(this, "auth", {});
        BaseRouter.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    // requires auth by default?
    authDefault: false,

    /**
     * Check the `auth` hash for a callback. Returns `authDefault` if
     * the callback is not specified.
     * @param  {String}  callbackName name of the function.
     * @return {Boolean}   true if the callback is private.
     */
    hasAuth: function(callbackName) {
        return _.result(this.auth, callbackName, this.authDefault);
    },

    // To easily override the auth logic in a specific router
    checkAuth: function(){
        return Auth.isAuthenticated();
    },

    execute: function(callback, args, name) {
        if (this.hasAuth(name) && !this.checkAuth()) {
            this.navigate('/login', { trigger: true });
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

## Defining the specific routers

Then for each of your router, extend `BaseRouter`.

```
var SpecificRouter = BaseRouter.extend({
    routes: {
        '*otherwise': 'home', // notice the catch all
        'public': 'publicRoute',
        'private': 'privateRoute',
        'unspecified': 'defaultAccessRoute'
    },

    /**
     * The auth hash works like this:
     * "functionName": [boolean, true if needs auth]
     * 
     * home and publicRoute could be left out as it's the default here.
     */
    auth: {
        home: false, // public
        publicRoute: false, // public
        privateRoute: true, // needs authentication
        // defaultAccessRoute will be public because BaseRouter
        // defines `authDefault: false`.
    },

    home: function() {},
    publicRoute: function() {},
    privateRoute: function() {},
    defaultAccessRoute: function() {},

});
```

And for a router which all routes are private by default:

```
var PrivateRouter = BaseRouter.extend({
    authDefault: true,
    routes: {
        '*otherwise': 'home', // private
        'only-private': 'onlyPrivate', // private
    },

    // ...snip...

    /**
     * Optional example on how to override the default auth behavior.
     */
    checkAuth: function() {
        var defaultAuthResult = PrivateRouter.__super__.checkAuth.call(this);
        return this.specificProperty && defaultAuthResult;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In github you can find many solution for calling some methods before router's execution. For `marionette` you can use ideas from [marionette-lite](https://github.com/noveogroup-amorgunov/marionette-lite) extension based in filters system.

You should define filter, for example `RequresAuthFilter` as:

```
import { Filter } from 'marionette-lite';

const RequresAuthFilter = Filter.extend({
  name: 'requresAuth', // name is used in controller for detect filter
  async: true, // async mode
  execution: Filter.Before, 
  handler(fragment, args, next) {
    // Requesting server to check if user is authorised
    $.ajax({
      url: '/auth',
      success: () => {
        this.isSignedIn = true;
        next();
      },
      error: () => {
        Backbone.navigate('login', true);
      }
    });
  },
});
```

or short sync way:

```
import { Filter } from 'marionette-lite';

const RequresAuthFilter = Filter.extend({
  name: 'requresAuth',    
  handler(fragment, args) {
    if (!window.isSignedIn) {
      Backbone.navigate('login', true);
    }
  },
});
```

And add this filter to `Controller` as:

```
const AppController = Marionette.Object.extend({
  // Add available filters map
  filtersMap: [
      new RequresAuthFilter()
  ],

  filters: {
    // e.g. Action that need authentication and if user isn't
    // authenticated gets redirect to login page
    requresAuth: ['logout', 'private'],
  },

  logout() { /* ... */ },
  private() { /* ... */ }
});
```